# Implementing MVI Architecture in Android without Mosby

Tags: java, android, kotlin, architecture

I am trying to implement MVI Architecture in Android, but don't want to use Mosby Library. I want to learn the basics first.

I am building a sample app where when I press a button, text in the textview changes(initially the text is something else). Here is the code for MainActivity and MainPresenter.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MainContract.View {

    lateinit var mPresenter: MainContract.Presenter
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        mPresenter = MainPresenter()
        mPresenter.attachPresenter(this)
        bind()
    }

    @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    private fun bind() {
        mPresenter.states().subscribe({ state ->
            render(state)
        }, {
            Log.e("error", "Error is: ", it)
            it.printStackTrace()
        })
        mPresenter.addIntents(intents())
    }

    override fun intents(): Observable<MainIntent> {
        return Observable.merge(
            initialIntent(),
            clickIntent()
        )
    }

    override fun render(state: MainViewState) {
        btn_show.isEnabled = state.isEnabledButton
        helloWorldTextView.text = state.message
        loadingIndicator.visibility = if (state.isLoading) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    }

    private fun initialIntent(): Observable<MainIntent.InitialIntent> = Observable.just(MainIntent.InitialIntent)

    private fun clickIntent(): Observable<MainIntent.ClickIntent> {
        return btn_show.clicks().map { MainIntent.ClickIntent("Eureka") }
    }


}



class MainPresenter : MainContract.Presenter {

    private val intentsSubject: PublishSubject<MainIntent> = PublishSubject.create()

    override fun states(): Observable<MainViewState> {
        return statesObservable
    }

    private lateinit var view: MainContract.View

    override fun attachPresenter(view: MainContract.View) {
        this.view = view
    }

    @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    override fun addIntents(intents: Observable<MainIntent>) {
        intents.subscribe(intentsSubject)
    }

    private val reducer =
        BiFunction { previousState: MainViewState, result: MainResult ->
            when (result) {
                is MainResult.InitialResult.InFlight -> previousState.copy(
                    isLoading = true,
                    message = "Initial Result",
                    isEnabledButton = false
                )
                is MainResult.InitialResult.Success -> previousState.copy(
                    isLoading = true,
                    message = "Initial Success",
                    isEnabledButton = true
                )
                is MainResult.InitialResult.Error -> previousState.copy(
                    isLoading = false,
                    message = "Error Initially",
                    isEnabledButton = true
                )

                is MainResult.ClickedResult.Success -> previousState.copy(
                    isLoading = false,
                    message = System.currentTimeMillis().toString(),
                    isEnabledButton = true
                )
                is MainResult.ClickedResult.Error -> previousState.copy(
                    isLoading = false,
                    message = "Error Clicked",
                    isEnabledButton = true
                )
                is MainResult.ClickedResult.InFlight -> previousState.copy(
                    isLoading = true,
                    message = "Clicked In Flight",
                    isEnabledButton = false
                )
            }
        }

    private fun actionFromIntent(intent: MainIntent): MainAction {
        if (intent is MainIntent.InitialIntent) {
            return MainAction.InitialAction
        } else if (intent is MainIntent.ClickIntent) {
            return MainAction.ClickedAction("Hello")
        } else {
            return MainAction.InitialAction
        }
    }

    private var actionProcessor: ObservableTransformer<MainAction, MainResult> = ObservableTransformer { actions ->
        actions.publish { shared ->
            Observable.merge<MainResult>(
                shared.ofType(MainAction.InitialAction::class.java).compose(initialActionProcessor),
                shared.ofType(MainAction.ClickedAction::class.java).compose(clickActionProcessor)
            )
        }
    }

    private val initialActionProcessor =
        ObservableTransformer<MainAction.InitialAction, MainResult.InitialResult> { action: Observable<MainAction.InitialAction> ->
            action.switchMap {
                Observable.just("hello initially")
                    .map { MainResult.InitialResult.Success(it) }
                    .cast(MainResult.InitialResult::class.java)
                    .onErrorReturn { MainResult.InitialResult.Error(it.message!!) }
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .startWith { MainResult.InitialResult.InFlight }
            }
        }

    private val clickActionProcessor =
        ObservableTransformer<MainAction.ClickedAction, MainResult.ClickedResult> { action: Observable<MainAction.ClickedAction> ->
            Observable.just("Click").map { message ->
                MainResult.ClickedResult.Success(message)
            }.cast(MainResult.ClickedResult::class.java)
                .onErrorReturn { MainResult.ClickedResult.Error("Error") }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .startWith { MainResult.ClickedResult.InFlight }
        }

    private val statesObservable: Observable<MainViewState> = compose()

    private fun compose(): Observable<MainViewState> {
        return intentsSubject
            .map {
                actionFromIntent(it)
            }
            .compose(actionProcessor)
            .scan(MainViewState.idle(), reducer)
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .replay(1)
            .autoConnect(0)
    }


}
```

Problem is that only the Inital event is fired and nothing else. The code doesn't respond to clicks, render is called only initially once.

Also, if I remove the `startWith{}` from the **actionProcessors** code responds to clicks, but only once. After that, nothing happens.

Does anyone see issue with the code? I have been trying to get my head around this problem for a while now.

Comment: It's not straight answer to your question. But if you implement what's below, you probably won't have the problem you **actually** asked about and you'll have easier MVI solution. You probably try to merge https://speakerdeck.com/jakewharton/the-state-of-managing-state-with-rxjava-devoxx-us-2017, http://hannesdorfmann.com/android/mosby3-mvi-1 and https://medium.com/@oldergod/managing-state-with-rxjava-b0798a6c5757 ideas. Take a look here: https://proandroiddev.com/taming-state-in-android-with-elm-architecture-and-kotlin-part-1-566caae0f706 - it's simpler. Part 1 and 2 should be enough. I tried

Answer (score 0):

If you implement what's below, you probably won't have the problem you actually asked about and you'll have easier MVI solution.

You probably try to merge https://speakerdeck.com/jakewharton/the-state-of-managing-state-with-rxjava-devoxx-us-2017, http://hannesdorfmann.com/android/mosby3-mvi-1 and https://medium.com/@oldergod/managing-state-with-rxjava-b0798a6c5757 ideas.

Take a look here: https://proandroiddev.com/taming-state-in-android-with-elm-architecture-and-kotlin-part-1-566caae0f706 - it's simpler. Part 1 and 2 should be enough.

I tried the 1st approach and was repulsed by initial complexity. In 2nd approach you don't have Action, Intent, Result, but Msg instead. It's simpler to reason about.

There's also new MVI course - but haven't checked it yet.

**Current approach:**

I tried mentioned Elm Architecture, but it is not complete. There are at least 2 problems:

1. Only one request can get through queue at one moment. Some RxJava
   should do the trick (groupBy with 2 streams: ui, background
   probably).
2. parallel requests would update the same state, so you should differentiate `DataStates` inside your `UiState`. So different state for different part of UI.

Before writing actual fixes we realised, this is not the way to go ATM: announced Composables could do the MVI trick: smooth and precise data transition to specific parts of UI.